# Code is returning an Error in CodeCademy only. Cant find issue

Tags: javascript

In lesson 5/30 in Intro to Objects 2 for CodeCademy they want you to practice bracket notation. if i run this code on jsfiddle it prints out 'programmer' to the console but on codecademy it gives an error saying "Oops, try again. It looks like james' job was not logged to the console." Any suggestions?

```
var james = {
    job: "programmer",
    married: false
};

// set to the first property name of "james"
var aProperty = "job";

// print the value of the first property of "james" 
// using the variable "aProperty"

console.log(james[aProperty]);
```

Comment: The code is correct (and it works "as expected"). There is something else you didn't mention. PS: what is the complete task? Not sure if we need to guess it.

Comment: Take advantage of the ability to use variables with bracket notation.

In line 7, set aProperty to a string of the first property in james (ie. the job property).

Then print james's job using bracket notation and aProperty

Comment: The code you provided does what this assignment asks. It would be helpful if you provided a screenshot of the whole page.

Comment: i dont know how to explain it  but when i ran the same exact code again to take the screenshot it said success.

Comment: Next time try to take a screenshot before you ask! ;-D

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with this, also. Instead of using:

```
var aProperty = james["job"];
console.log(aProperty);
```

Try:

```
var aProperty = ["job"];
console.log(aProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  If anyone stumbles across this, try changing browsers.

I had to switch from Chrome to I.E. for the code to work.

The code provided by Austin is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're supposed to assign  the variable 'aProperty' with the bracket notation.

try:

```
var aProperty = james["job"];
console.log(aProperty);
```

Comment: "set aProperty to a string of the first property in james. Then print james's job using bracket notation and aProperty" --- your "belief" is not what the assignment asks.